# set rules for openvpn by iptables in firewall CentOS 6.2

Tags: iptables, openvpn

Firewall (FW), three leg:

- eth0: 172.16.1.101
- eth1: 192.168.99.99 (LAN)
- eth2: 10.0.0.1 (DMZ)

I installed `openvpn` in FW by tunnel mode, already ok:

- tun0: 192.168.10.0/24.

If I use `shorewall` and `squid` proxy FW is ok. At beside can connect to FW, LAN, DMZ using my company services.

Now, I want to use `iptables` rules + `squid` proxy.

What do I set rules for openvpn?

And I have set rules below but not connect to server firewall installed `openvpn`:

- Packet forwarding

  `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
- OpenVPN

  `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT`
- Allow TUN interface connections to OpenVPN server

  `iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT`
- Allow TUN interface connections to be forwarded through other interfaces

  ```
  iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  ```
- NAT the VPN client traffic to the internet

  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
- If your default iptables OUTPUT value is not ACCEPT, you will also need a line like:

  ```
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
  ```